# Azure: custom mappings with storage account

Tags: azure

I have a couple of web domains registered with GoDaddy.

Using GoDaddy's "DNS Management", I could redirect any calls to my domain to a website hosted on Azure.  All good so far.

Azure now allows you to host (simple) Angular websites in a Storage Account, which is cheaper than hosting a full-blown Web App on Azure.

For example, here's a link to my sample Angular app, happily running in a Storage Account, and I would like to link it to my GoDaddy *www.mikesexamplesite.com* domain.

https://mikegledhill.z19.web.core.windows.net/

The Azure Portal pages do have a "Custom Domain" option for Storage Accounts, suggesting that I could redirect any calls from my GoDaddy domain to this Azure domain... but (unlike with a full-blown Azure website) I completely can't get this to work.

[image]

Note that, on this webpage, if it *can't* find a matching CNAME record on GoDaddy, you'll get an error message when you click on Save.  But, even when I *don't* get an error (so Azure *has* confirmed that it's found the CNAME record), when I open a browser and go onto my GoDaddy URL, I still get a 404 error.

**Has anyone managed to get a Custom Domain linked to an Azure Storage Account s to work properly ?**

Obviously, yes, I've Google'd this, followed [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain), which work fine on regular Azure web sites but not for Storage Accounts...  This stuff just doesn't seem to work properly....

Comment: Have you seen this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?

Comment: Yup, I followed this, I've done this, and when I click on Save, Azure happily accepts it - so no errors are shown.  But I still get a 404, when I try to browse to my domain's root URL.